# Two ways an instance variable can be initialized when an object is constructed?

Tags: java

I know you guys hate helping with homework, but I thought I might ask anyways...

So, I have the question:

> Describe two ways in which an instance variable can be initialized when an object is constructed.

Now, the first way would obviously be to assign the instance variable to a formal parameter of the constructor:

```
public class Example {
    private int valueOne;
    public Example(int val1) {
        valueOne = val1;
    }
}
```

However, I still need another way.

One possibility could be to simply assign the instance variable in the constructor to a value not accepted as a parameter of the constructor:

```
public class Example {
    private int valueTwo;
    public Example() {
        valueTwo = 2;
    }
}
```

But that just seems like a cheap solution to the problem that isn't *that* different from the first solution.

So, I was wondering about something like this:

```
public class Example {
    private int valueOne = 1;
}
```

However, I was wondering if that still assigns the `valueOne` the value `1` at the time of the object's construction, or does something different?

And, if it does do something different, what would be another alternative to the problem? Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: We do not hate helping with homework, as long as you first put some effort in it and show this in the question, as you did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two ways are the two ways I would have thought about.

The latter initializes the value when the object is constructed. It actually happens even before the constructor runs (you can test that):

```
class Example {
    private int valueOne = 1;
    public Example(int value)
    {
        System.out.println(valueOne);
        valueOne = value;
        System.out.println(valueOne);
    }
}

...

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Example(2);
}
```

This prints:

```
1
2
```

Comment: It's actually part of the constructor. It happens just after the implicit or explicit call to `super()`.

Comment: Yeah, but what I mean is that it happens before any code that you can write in a constructor runs as the example shows.

Comment: omg, yes you can, but in the super you don't have acces  to this member variable

Comment: @Peter Ivanov Yup. Although a base class constructor can call "virtual" methods in your class.

Answer (score 1):

I am not expert in Java, however just for curiosity I did a google search and got this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html It says that There are two alternatives to using a constructor to initialize instance variables: initializer blocks and final methods, however if you consider during the construction [that's your original question] of the object your answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

A third way:

```
class Example {
      public int member;

      { // This is an instance initializer and is called before any constructor when an instance is created.
        member = 1;
      }
}
```

But people usually avoid instance initializers as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, `private int valueOne = 1;` would initialize the variable at instance creation.

Answer (score 0):

You already have your answer. If you are working with an IDE, I suggest you fire up your debugger, place a breakpoint at the line where you call

```
new Example();
```

and go through it step by step. Do this with both of your suggested answers and see what happens in which order

Answer (score 0):

Initialising the field in its definition is the equivalent of writing the assignment immediate after the explicit or implicit call to `super()` in each constructor (that doesn't explicitly call a `this()`).

To show this, run the following code (this being Stack Overflow, I haven't so much as compiled it):

```
abstract class Base {
    protected Base() {
        print();
    }
    protected abstract void print();
}
public class Derived extends Base {
    private int x = 1;
    public Derived() {
        //super(); - automatically generate by javac
    }
    @Override protected void print() {
        System.err.println(x);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Derived();
    }
}
```

I believe C# behaves differently (but you can't use `this` in field initialisation expressions) - correct me if I'm wrong.